# Can not connect MySQL when client call method in server using webservice

Tags: android, mysql, web-services

I has a trouble with JDBC connection
Webservice (Axis2) designed to return a list string (select from DB)
**@Webservice**

```
public ArrayList<String> loadDatabase(String txtSearch) {
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/smd";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "passw0rd";

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");
        rs = st.executeQuery("Select * FROM medicine");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("NAME");
            myList.add(name);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
    return myList;
}
```

@Client

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> addData = new ArrayList<String>();
            MedicineJDBCFinderStub mStub = new MedicineJDBCFinderStub();
            MedicineJDBCFinderStub.LoadDatabase stub = new MedicineJDBCFinderStub.LoadDatabase();
            stub.setTxtSearch("t");
            LoadDatabaseResponse result = mStub.loadDatabase(stub);
} catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I deployed successful, but when I run Main class in Client or run on Android(using KSOAP), I have same problem that is

```
    SEVERE: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/smd
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/smd
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.med.dic.finder.MedicineJDBCFinder.loadDatabase(MedicineJDBCFinder.java:27)
```

Althought I add mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar to library and connect successfull in Main(not using Webservice).

Anyone can help me resolve the problem? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, I don't know much about Java with Android. Try adding

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

above your Connection statement. When I remove that in any of my projects using MySQL and JDBC I get the same error as yours.

Comment: Woa! It run successfully when I follow your support. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I was able to help.